# Formik and react-autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm looking for a way to connect two libraries: [react-autocomplete](https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete) and [formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik). However, I can not find a way.

Please, give me some tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of `setFieldValue` provided by Formik.

```
<Autocomplete
      getItemValue={(item) => item.label}
      items={[{ label: 'apple' }, { label: 'banana' }, { label: 'pear' }]}
      renderItem={(item, isHighlighted) => <div style={{ background: isHighlighted ? 'lightgray' : 'white' }}>{item.label}</div>}
      value={values.value}
      onChange={(e) => setFieldValue('value', e.target.value)}
      onSelect={(val) => setFieldValue('value', val)}
/>
```

Sample code: https://codesandbox.io/s/n0y93104qp

Comment: But the search does not work. It does not filter the results